# MySQL Shell always gives error no matter what I type

Tags: mysql

I have even switched to the `\sql` mode.
I have tried `\connect root@localhost;`
I have tried with `mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 --user=root -p;`
I am new to this . I installed the entire .msi package too. 
If i run the MySql Command Line Client, everything works.
This brings me to another doubt. What is the purpose of MySQl shell?

Comment: What ".msi package" are you talking about specifically? And what exactly is the error you're getting? It's kind of hard to help you with so little information about what your actual problem is.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ - the .msi package link for downloading mysql.

Comment: the exact error is : "ERROR: Not connected. "

Comment: OK, can you [edit] the question to show what exactly you've tried, and what the output was? Have you looked at [the user manual for MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/)? I think it answers the "what is the purpose" part of your question very clearly, and includes details on how to connect to a database.

Comment: Hey, the user manual solved the issue. Thanks a lot :)